# How to pass .strftime() to groupby in jinja

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to group items in list by it's date so I decided to use strftime as my tool but it just gives an error

```html
<ul>{% for day, item in items|groupby("date_created.day") %}
    <li>{{ day }}
      <ul>{% for i in item %}
        <li>{{ i.product }}
      {% endfor %}</ul>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}</ul>
```

[That's the output of code example above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrtQ9.png)

But if I change .day to .strftime('%Y-%m-%d') it gives me an error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'datetime.datetime object' has no attribute "strftime('%Y-%m-%d')"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `group_by` expression doesn't support arbitrary python expressions. You will need to compute an additional field (e.g. `formatted_date_created`), and add it to each of your `items` elements, in your view function (the one that calls the template)